# Animating SVG path in circular form

Tags: html, svg

I have made this with svg. I am having problem with animating the progress. When I animate the path(the blue progress) it is very clumsy . That is it doesn't properly animate on  curved path. Where did i go wrong?. And i am not using any library for that. [image: svg circular progress]
[Github link for svg progress bar animation](https://github.com/deepakbhattarai/circular-progress/blob/master/animation-test.html)

Comment: i think this will help you http://jakearchibald.com/2013/animated-line-drawing-svg/

Comment: i want to use the SVG and SMIL animation and not requestAnimationFrame and CSS transitions

Comment: Is it possible to put it on a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I have made a repository on github. The library is lengthy.